# Angular2 Unable to print JSON Nested array

Tags: json, angular, typescript

Angular2 Unable to print JSON Nested array
help me with nested array problem. Unable to print User_name, User_id and User IRN..

My Component.ts

```
this.apiService.getIM().subscribe((getIM) => {
  this.iOverview = getIM['message'];
  console.log(this.iOverview); //This print the whole array.
});
```

HTML Code

```
<tr *ngFor="let iUsers of iOverview?.response?.i_details?.user_details | slice:0:10;">
  <td>    
    <div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)"
      class="text-default font-weight-semibold letter-icon-title">{{ iUsers.user_name }}</a>
    </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

My Json Output

```
{
    "message": {
        "response": {
      "res_type": "IM Users",  //able to print this value
            "acc_id": "1234567890",
            "i_details": [
                {
                    "user_details": [
                        [
                            {
                                "user_name": "admins", //not able to print this value.
                                "user_id": "MyGroups1",
                                "user_arn": "user:763526717345"
                            }
            ]
          ]  
        }  
      ]  
    }  
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you noticed that the properties you are trying to access are nested in another array? "user_details": [[...]]. Try accessing it like this:

```
*ngFor="let iUsers of iOverview?.response?.i_details?.user_details[0]
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I solved it. But I need to put another array  

`*ngFor="let iUsers of iOverview?.response?.i_details[0]?.user_details[0]`  

This is my working code. i_details is also an array.